How to resolve ngrx store dispatch issue in unit test in angular 18
NGRX Store dispatch issue is not working in my code. Getting below error. So, How to resolve this issue.

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'dispatch')

app.component.spect.ts:
it('should dispatch action and handle success response', () => {

 const actionInfo: INgrxActionInfo = 
 vasActionInfo[VasActionEnum.DELETE_DATA] as INgrxActionInfo;
 const payload = {
 inputData: {
    name: data.name,
    place: data.place,
 },
 };
 
 const dispatchSpyon = spyOn(store, 'dispatch').and.callThrough();
 expect(dispatchSpyon).toHaveBeenCalledWith(vasNgrxAction.action(actionInfo, true, payload));


});

